# How did the "Wheel of Theodorus" become known as the "Wheel of Einstein"?

Tags: geometry, einstein, naming-conventions

I've desperately searched the Internet, to no avail, to find a citation of how the "Wheel of Theodorus" became known as the "Wheel of Einstein" as claimed by [***Wikipedia***](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiral_of_Theodorus) and [***Wolfram***](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EinsteinSpiral.html).

Comment: Welcome to HSMSE. Please include your question in the body of the question, instead of putting it only in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that "The Wheel of Theodorus is also called the Spiral of Theodorus,
the Square Root Spiral, Einstein Spiral, or Pythagorean Spiral," [[W.Lombard]](https://www.geogebra.org/m/BwKQyu69) I doubt you'll find anything other than random common usage as a reason for naming.
( also  “Wurzel Spirale" )

Comment: Using internet search engines, I cannot find any mention of "Einstein Spiral" that predates 2004.

Comment: Thank you @njuffa for the time-line on your search.